# Determine index of triangle point that remains after selecting the other two

Tags: c, algorithm

*(This feels like a really dumb problem, but I'm having trouble coming up with a "good" solution, despite a lot of vague Google searching.)*

Let's say I have an array of triangles, and within each is an array containing the triangle's three points (indices 0, 1, 2). In the process of searching for a triangle that contains an edge, I find the triangle and record the indices of the two points on the edge in variables (i.e. 2 and 0). These two can be selected in any order.

Now I need to know which index was **not** selected. So if the edge was on indices 2 and 0 of the given triangle, then index 1 is the remaining point that was not selected.

Is there a way to determine this algorithmically, without using a tree of if statements for each combination? Perhaps a bit mask, though I'm not exactly sure how for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have two distinct integers `a`, `b` out of 0, 1, 2, then the following trick will give you the third:

```
c = 3^a^b;
```

If `a` and `b` are 0 and 1, this produces 2.  If they are 0 and 2, this produces 1.  And if they are 1 and 2, this produces 0.  Note that `^` is the bitwise exclusive-OR operator.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
c = 3-a-b;
```

to achieve the same result.

More generally, if you have three numbers `x`, `y`, and `z`, and `a` and `b` are two of those numbers, then `c = s-a-b` is the third, where `s = x+y+z`.  Alternatively, `c = p^a^b` is the third, where `p = x^y^z`.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping to find. Thanks!